Are there any instances of ancient kings or chiefs dueling or engaging in other physical contests to assert their authority?
In popular fiction chiefs/kings or heirs to the throne often duel or engage in physical contests for kingship e.g the archery contest in the Odyssey.
Did any such duels or physical contests occur?

There is actually a Wikipedia page on this subject(single combat). Sadly, histories of ancient and (Medieval) battles are almost always somewhere on the spectrum from "semi-legendary" to completely legendary. Just from the sheer weight of reports of it, it seems that kind of thing happened though. Does that page answer the question? If not, why not?

@T.E.D.   I'm specifically asking about dueling for the position of chieftain not duels between leaders of different armies>

Ah. That's supposedly how the Anglo-Saxons did things (or rather Things) in the early days when there was a dispute. I can't dig up a reference to it with a quick search. I may try more detailed later.

@user122938, The question should clearly state what you're asking for. Modifying the question in comments decreases the probability you'll get an answer.  Are you looking for the whole world? For a particular variety of "ancient"?  Does the Illiad count ?  What research have you done?  What about Andrew Jackson's duel? What does "assert authority" mean?

@MCW yes the entire world  I've found instances of dueling like the viking hollmgang   however I'm specifically looking for instances where peoples dueled for chieftain or kingship or when kings fought duels to assert their authority.

The classical Germanic way was to actually elect their kings (one of the things a Thing was for). If it was a close election, combat might decide it (one way or the other). The early Anglo-Saxon kingdoms didn't have a set succession order either, although there was a royal family it helped to be a part of.

You start with two very significant words: popular fiction. It's a popular theme to write about, but happened seldom in reality.
It's not very practical, from a leader's point of view. You are a tribal leader or king, with a band of followers. Why would you, the leader, go into hand to hand combat? That's why you have followers for. You pay them handsomely, make the buggers earn their living!
It did happen, but was extremely rare. To give you an example: The Roman army had a complex reward system, with the corona's and the triumph at the top. A corona was awarded for personal bravery to any man deserving it. A triumph was awarded to a triumphant general victorious in battle.
However, there was an even higher reward: the Spolia Optima. This was the greatest possible honor a Roman could achieve. It was only awarded when a commanding general in battle defeated an enemy general in combat himself. It was awarded in the entire history of Rome only a few times, less than fingers on your hand.
The last — theoretical — winner was Marcus Licinius Crassus, the grandson of the triumvir. I said theoretical, because he was general in command involved in personal combat with his opposite, and did claim it, it was denied by Augustus. Too political sensitive. After him nobody ever got one.
Other (and earlier) winners were:

Aulus Cornelius Cossus
Marcus Claudius Marcellus

There were more winners, but these are mythical or semi-mythical. Romulus is one of them. The Roman empire lasted a thousand years (give or take), with 2 official winners, 1 denied and 2 (semi) mythical. That's how rare this kind of combat is.
What you describe did happen, but on a lower level and still rare. Before horses could be ridden, warriors entered the battlefield in chariots pulled by ponies. They dismounted and fought hand to hand, the charioteer remained close by to get his boss out of trouble if need be. In the classical world that was the age of Homer. On the British isles that era lasted longer, the Romans had to fight of several armies with chariots. Caesar writes about many chariots he encountered, and Boudica's army contained chariots as well, though not as many as Caesar encountered.
Once horses could be ridden, the importance of chariots diminished. With it the need for single combat. From a practical point, single combat is for highly trained warriors in the prime of their life. Kings usually (not always, of course) are either too old, or reaching the end of their military life.
That's where the problem is: unless you're talking about tribal warfare or very small kingdoms (as on the British Isles), a commander in chief is usually too old for single combat. Another reason why it seldom happend is that one of the two had to loose. Not only his life, but also his kingdom. That's a tough proposition, especially if you have a bunch of guys hired for that job.
A nice what-if for you are the battles fought by Alexander the Great against Xerxes. In the Battle of Gaugamela, Alexander attempted to reach Xerxes but failed because Xerxes fled the field. Xerxes certainly wasn't the only leader who avoided combat.
